# End continuous loop and restart script with same hotkey - AutoHotkey

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I have this script below. It has a continuous loop in it.

I want to be able to: **press the hotkey again (ie F4) and for the continuous loop to end, and for the script to restart**.

I've tried using #MaxThreadsPerHotkey but have not had much luck. Anyone's help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 10
F4::
Send, z
Sleep, 100
Send, ^{Left}
Loop,
{
Sleep, 30000
WinActivate, ahk_exe PotPlayerMini64.exe
Send, z
SoundBeep
}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use timers instead of `Sleep` loops. This should work:

```
F4::
    Send, z
    Sleep, 100
    Send, ^{Left}
    SetTimer, SendLoop, 3000
Return

SendLoop:
    WinActivate, ahk_exe PotPlayerMini64.exe
    Send, z
    SoundBeep
Return
```